# Query posts without a specific ID

Tags: query-posts, posts

How would we query posts as long as the post does not equal the ID 2047?

Here is the current query.

```
<?php 
$args1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'options',
    'tag_slug__and' => array( $triplevel, $divingtrip, 'accommodation' ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'offset' => 1,
); 
query_posts( $args1 ); while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

I tried this...

```
query_posts( $args1 . 'p!=2047' );
```

..to no effect.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the things you can do with a query are described in the [Codex page for WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)

You need to use the 'post__not_in' parameter eg:

```
$args = array(    
              'post__not_in' => array('34','54'), // post ids   
              'post_type' => 'page'   
             );`
```